# requestCert not working (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use client authentication, but requestCert is not working. When the site is loaded, there isn't any prompt to select a certificate.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key:    fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key'),
  cert:   fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt'),

  // This is necessary only if using the client certificate authentication.
  requestCert: true,

  // This is necessary only if the client uses the self-signed certificate.
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('/etc/pki/tls/private/device.key') ]
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.write("Hello.\n");
  if(req.client.authorized) {
    res.write('Access granted.\n');
  }
  else {
    res.write('Access denied.\n');
  }
  res.end();
}).listen(5000);
```

What's wrong? I've used example codes! Thanks.